# Init jQuery after ng-options were loaded

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a cshtml file with a multiselect. Now I have to move that multiselect from being populated with .NET to being populated with AngularJS.
I have created the select as showed below, but when the page loads, to my multiselect that was populated with Angular is added a `display: none` attribute and the old jQuery multiselect appears with no data in it.

My guess would be that when the jQuery multiselect is initialized, there is no data present. So when angular wants to populate the multiselect it creates a new one with the desired values, but I'm nt sure why it isn't displayed.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="box">
            <div ng-controller="CreateConfigCtrl" class="body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Configuration name</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input type="text" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-lg-4"></label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <select multiple class="multipleSelect" ng-multiple="true" ng-model="object" ng-options="obj.Name for obj in model.XMLColumns" options-load="model.XMLColumns" size="16" name="test"></select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                    <div class="form-group" id="concatFieldsTextBoxes"></div>
                    <div id="Buttons" style="clear: left">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save config" />
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        function initSectionList() {
            $(".multipleSelect").each(function (element) {
                var b = $(this);
                if (!b.data('init-multi')) {
                    b.multiselect2side({ 'search': 'Search: ' });
                    b.data('init-multi', true);
                }
            });
        }

        initSectionList();
    });
</script>
```

Above is my CSHTML page and below my CreateConfigCtrl.js

```
var app = angular.module('PdfConfig.CreateController', [])

app.controller('CreateConfigCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.model = {};

    $http.get('CreateVM').success(function (data) {
        $scope.model = data;
    });
}]);
```

I've read about adding a directive with $timeout or $watch, but I don't understand how to initialize that jQuery function after all the ng-options were loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ng-if to create ng-options after service response then call your jquery function with $timeout:-
HTML:-

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="box">
                <div ng-controller="CreateConfigCtrl" class="body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Configuration name</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-8">
                                <input type="text" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-lg-4"></label>
                            <div class="col-lg-8" ng-if="flag">
                                <select multiple class="multipleSelect" ng-multiple="true" ng-model="object" ng-options="obj.Name for obj in model.XMLColumns" options-load="model.XMLColumns" size="16" name="test"></select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr />
                        <div class="form-group" id="concatFieldsTextBoxes"></div>
                        <div id="Buttons" style="clear: left">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save config" />
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

            function initSectionList() {
                $(".multipleSelect").each(function (element) {
                    var b = $(this);
                    if (!b.data('init-multi')) {
                        b.multiselect2side({ 'search': 'Search: ' });
                        b.data('init-multi', true);
                    }
                });
            }



    </script>
```

Angular js code:

```
var app = angular.module('PdfConfig.CreateController', [])

app.controller('CreateConfigCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http,$timeout) {
    $scope.model = {};
    $scope.flag=false;
    $http.get('CreateVM').success(function (data) {
        $scope.model = data;
         $scope.flag=true;
        $timeout(function(){ 
        $(".multipleSelect").each(function (element) {
                var b = $(this);
                if (!b.data('init-multi')) {
                    b.multiselect2side({ 'search': 'Search: ' });
                    b.data('init-multi', true);
                }
            });
      });         
   });
}]);
```

Comment: That did the trick. I've moved all that jQuery from the HTML to the $timeout function. But now I have another problem: the Object ng-model isn't populated anymore, despite the fact that the attribute selected is added to the options in the multiselect.

Comment: may be you are lossing scope so use $scope.$apply()

Comment: I'm not sure I know where to place this, because I'm not using "object" anywhere in my controller. I've did a little googling but I'm still not sure how to apply that.

Comment: see the edited answer and try to appy that and I would not suggest you to use juery inside angularjs

Answer (score 0):

the way you are trying to do is bad practice.

you need to [create a directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for your multiselect2side and use it.